# formatting YAML headers in R

Tags: r, yaml, r-markdown, papaja

When using the R papaja package template, I figured how to justify (and further format the text in the sections following the YAML header by adding LaTEX packages to the YAML header. E.g:

```
header-includes:
- \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

However this will not work for the text in the actual header which contains the text of the abstract of the article. Is there a way to justify the text in the actual YAML header?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `papaja` is intended to create APA-style documents and is working as intended. That said, in this case it's easy to achieve what you are trying to do by including `\justifying` in the abstract field of the YAML front matter.

```yaml
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[document]{ragged2e}

abstract: |
  \justifying
  
  This is the abstract.
```